# Animate like in Real Life in Blender (Stop Motion?)

Tags: animation

Is there an approach or a way on animating scenes in blender like we do it in real life with stop motion? Adding and changing objects in between the shots.

I know that there a shape keys for example, but you can't "add" objects or vertices, as far as I am informed.

Comment: There was a Key Mesh project in that direction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPvLQH17Y2Q&ab_channel=askNK but as I know it was abandoned

Comment: this might interest you : https://youtu.be/noexK8EIwzg. I just typed "Blender stop motion" on youtube.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed can't add vertices. But you can just have different objects available, and animate their visibility.

Though that's the manual repetitive way.

Ideally, you have a rig with different models (for example, different face models), and there is a controller in the rig that will drive which model is visible. So that for each frame, you can choose which face model to show for example.

Comment: You can add and remove geometry in animation if you use either generative modifiers or geometry nodes and this applies to character animation too. In the production of Sprite Fright, the sprites had geometry nodes and the geometry count was animated. This may also be useful in realistic animation if you use adaptive subdivision for example.

Comment: We are not talking about generating in-between geo nor particles. We are talking about having literal different models.

Comment: I was just making a remark on you saying "you can't add vertices" which is not completely true. I assume Edit Mode modifications was implied which is why you gave that answer but there are other ways.

Comment: I see, but I posted an answer to a question, not a broad statement with no context :P